# Bokeh Sphinx extension -- how to include data from CSV file?

Tags: bokeh, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am creating some documentation using Sphinx and I want to use the `bokeh.sphinxext` to include Bokeh plots with the documentation.  This seems like an easy thing to do given [this example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/sphinxext.html#bokeh-sphinxext-bokeh-plot).  However, the data that I want to use to generate the plot is stored within a CSV file.  I've tried putting my CSV file into the same directory, and using `.. include:: data.csv` in the same RST document, but that didn't work.

How can I reference an external file when creating Bokeh plots using Sphinx?

```
.. include:: data.csv

.. bokeh-plot::

    import pandas as pd
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

    output_file("example.html")

    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    p = figure(title="example", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    p.line(df['x'], df['y'], line_width=2)

    show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because of how the extension operates, the current working directory when the code executes (i.e. what is returned by the `os.getcwd()` function) is the top level of your Sphinx project. You will need to construct a path to your data file based on that. E.g. if your file is under the *source/docs* directory of your Sphinx project, it might be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.join('source', 'docs', 'data.csv')
```